# Tell custom HTML elements from native ones

Tags: javascript, polymer

In all the google web components tutorials it recommends a particular naming scheme for custom elements. The fact that they recommend such is probably for readability, but it begs the question: is there any way to reliably tell (programmatically) whether an HTML Element is custom or native? For instance polymer elements *are* instances of `HTML Element` and have all the correct properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, there wouldn't be any need to tell the difference between the two - your elements ought to act in every way like a native HTML element. However, if you absolutely had to target them specifically for a reason, you could look for elements that contain a hyphen in the name. Custom Elements have to have that hyphen (such as `<my-element>`) in order to be valid, whereas, if I recall correctly, no elements in the HTML5 spec include that hyphen.

**Note:** I haven't gone through the spec to double check this - but I do believe the lack of hyphens to be the case.

Comment: You're right. The custom elements spec requires that [custom element type names](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#dfn-custom-element-type) contain a hyphen character. That may not be enough to distinguish a custom element, but if an element's `tagName` contains no hyphen you know it isn't a custom one.

Comment: Note that `document.createElement` returns `HTMLUnknownElement` if the given element name isn't a known one (native, or custom element in the document registry). One could create a new document with an empty registry then create a new element with a given tag name. Checking for hyphens is a much less expensive first-check, though.